# About abstract and interface

Tags: c#, oop

Well i have one doubt about abstract relation "IS-A" and interface "HAS-A" functionality.

For example i have the following class:

```
public interface IReport
{
    int code            { get; set; }
    String description  { get; set; }

    void SetReport(String description, int code);
    void DeleteReport();
}

public abstract class BugReport : IReport
{
    public int? code           { get; set; }
    public String description { get; set; }

    public void IReport.SetReport(String description, int code)
    {
        this.description = description;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public void IReport.DeleteReport()
    {
        this.description = "";
        this.code = null;
    }
}
```

I know my BugReport class will have always the same implementation, but i can extend it on child classes if necessary. This criteria would match the abstract class "usage" but not the "IS-A" relation if used for example over this class:

```
public abstract Parser : BugReport
{
}
```

Is my Parser a BugReport? Well obviously not, but it seems the most logical choice, if i make my BugReport as an interface i would have to implement the functionality all over the classes i inherit from. So what i am doing wrong, should i keep using abstract independent of the IS-A relation mismatch or i should switch to interface?

Comment: I don't see the `[c++]` question?

Comment: I'll remove `c++` tag as this is pure `c#` question

Comment: C++ is not C#. Pick the appropriate language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider composition over inheritance.  Create a `BugReport` class, and use an instance of it in your `Parser` class to get the functionality you want, rather than getting the functionality by inheritance.

You can extend the functionality of the `BugReport` class on child classes, and just inject them into your `Parser` class as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this seems redundant to me;

```
int code            { get; set; }
String description  { get; set; }

void SetReport(String description, int code);
```

It's completely redundant to have property setters and a specialised method to set them all as well. What happens if you add a property? Do you change `SetReport`? Causing a cascade of changes wherver this method is used? Do you add an overload that takes a 3rd argument to cater for the new property and complicate the class further?

Keep the interface simple; provide ONE way to do something, else you just confuse the consumer of the class.

Beyond that, given you've provided no idea what a `Parser` is, then no one can say whether it IS a BugReport. But based purely on the lexicon, I would say no. In no dictionary I know of does BugReport=Parser.

Answer (score 0):

I also think you're misunderstanding IS-A vs HAS-A, based on your question.

You have not yet given an example of a HAS-A relationship.  The way your code is written above, a BugReport is an IReport, and a Parser is a BugReport (and therefore also a IReport).

The way to do a has-a relationship in this case is if Parser has a property which is a IReport.  For example:

```
public class Parser 
{
   public Parser(IReport reporter)
   {
       this.Report = reporter;
   }

   public IReport Report { get; set; }
}
```